# Intensity Poynting

Tags: dielectric, poynting-vector, intensity

Take a plane wave propagating in the $\hat{z}$ direction in a non-magnetic linear dielectric. The real electric field is then given by

$$\vec{E}(r,t) = E_0\, e^{-k_i z}\cos(k_R - \omega t)\, \hat{x} $$

where $k_i$ and $k_R$ stand for imaginary and real parts respectively.
Now knowing that the Poynting vector for instantaneous energy is $S = \mu^{-1}_0 (E \times B)$, the intensity $I$ is equal to

$$\frac{1}{2}(c\epsilon_0)n_R(\omega)E_0^2e^{-2k_iz}$$

where $n_R(\omega)$ is real part of the index of refraction. How did they get that intensity? Please explain in detail if you can. I'm quite confused...

Comment: The intensity is proportional to the norm of time average of Poynting vector.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article on the Poynting vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector#In_plane_waves) contains the derivation. It seems odd to me, though, that your textbook does not cover this derivation.